# Defining Partial Default Values

Tags: terraform

I am defining a variable in Terraform as:

```
variable 'var_a' {
   type = object({
      name = string
      enabled = bool
   })
   default = {
      name = "the_name"
      enabled = true
   }
}
```

If no value is passed to generate this variable, it would be populated with the values of "the_name" and true. However, I want to be able to still execute this code if only certain values of the variable object are provided.

For example, if I pass this as a variable:

```
var_a = {
   name = "another_name"
}
```

I would still like the enabled attribute to be set to true, based on the default value. When I try to use this code, it fails as it is expecting me to declare the enabled attribute.

Comment: *However, I would like to be able to populate some values of the variable object, and use the defaults of others.* can you clarify what you mean by this?

Comment: @Paolo, thank you for pointing out that ambiguity. Question edited to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some additional research, the answer for my case is to use the optional keyword ([Optional Object Type Attributes](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/type-constraints#optional-object-type-attributes)).

This allows one to specify whether the variable object attribute is optional, and provide a default value for that optional attribute.

Using optional with regard to the example above would look like:

Variable Definition:

```
variable "var_a" {
   type = object({
      name = string
      enabled = optional(bool, true)
   })
}
```

Usage:

```
var_a = {
   name = "another_name"
}
```

Variable Value:

```
{name = "another_name", enabled = true}
```

This yields the intended result for the variable, populating optional values with provided defaults.